# open restore point dialog c#

Tags: c#, cmd, process, restore-points

I am trying to open the restore point dialog from C# like

[image: here]

I'm using the following code:

```
Process.Start("SystemPropertiesProtection");
```

and from cmd:

```
public static string ExecuteCMD(IEnumerable<string> commands,
                                bool inBackground, 
                                bool runAsAdministrator ,
                                bool WaitProcessForExit)
{
    try 
    { 
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

        if (commands.Any())
        {
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = @" /C " + string.Join("&&", commands);
        }

        if (runAsAdministrator)
        {
            p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        }
                    
        if (inBackground)
        {
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        }
        else
        {
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        }

        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => { MessageBox.Show(e.Data); };
        p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => { MessageBox.Show(e.Data); };
        p.Start();

        if (WaitProcessForExit)
        {
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
        
        return "";//  p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        FRM_MSG f = new FRM_MSG();
        f.ShowDLG(" ",
                  ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace.ToString(),
                  FRM_MSG.MSGIcon.Error,
                  FRM_MSG.BTNS.One,
                  new string[] { "Ok" });
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

```
Executor.ExecuteCMD(new string[] { "SystemPropertiesProtection" }, true, false, false);
```

and even create shortcut to create restore point like this:

[image: this]

[image: this]

and open this shortcut with:

```
Process.Start(RestorePointShortcutFilePath);
```

but they always open three tabs and don't open the restore point tab

[image: this]

How do I open restore point dialog like shown on first image which has 5 tabs and not 3 tabs, my OS is Windows 7 64 bit? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you just enter `SystemProtectionProperties` on the normal commandline? Do you see the tabs then?

Comment: yes SystemProtectionProperties in cmd open restore point tab ,  but from c# open only three tabs and not restore point tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you're seeing is because of the [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) which is occurring because you're running your program as 32-bit on your 64-bit OS. Therefore, you're executing `%windir%\SysWOW64\SystemPropertiesProtection.exe` (ex: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SystemPropertiesProtection.exe).

There are a few ways to avoid this issue. Uncheck "Prefer 32-bit" (Project => <project name> Properties => Build => uncheck 'Prefer 32-bit'). Compile as x64, or check if your application is running as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS. If so, set the appropriate fully-qualified filename.

The documentation states:

> 32-bit applications can access the native system directory by
> substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32. WOW64
> recognizes Sysnative as a special alias used to indicate that the file
> system should not redirect the access. This mechanism is flexible and
> easy to use, therefore, it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file
> system redirection. Note that 64-bit applications cannot use the
> Sysnative alias as it is a virtual directory not a real one.

---

Try the following:

**Create a new Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)**

**Add an Application Manifest to your project**

**Note**: This is used to prompt the user to execute the program as Administrator.

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add New Item...**
- Select **Application Manifest File (Windows only)**
- Click **Add**

In **app.manifest**, replace

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

with

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

---

**Add the following using directives**:

- `using System.IO;`
- `using System.Diagnostics;`

```
private void OpenSystemPropertiesProtection()
{
    string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "System32", "SystemPropertiesProtection.exe");

    //environment variable windir has the same value as SystemRoot
    //use 'Sysnative' to access 64-bit files (in System32) if program is running as 32-bit process
    //use 'SysWow64' to access 32-bit files on 64-bit OS

    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
        filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "SysNative", "SystemPropertiesProtection.exe");
    
    Debug.WriteLine($"filename: {filename}");

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filename);
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);

    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

**Resources**:

- [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)
- [Running 32-bit Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/running-32-bit-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Use ShellExecute to execute the command.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "SystemPropertiesProtection";
info.UseShellExecute = true;

Process.Start(info);
```

I have tested this on Windows 11, but it will probably also work on Windows 7. Be aware that Windows 7 has reached end-of-life back in 2020. It shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: i try it in windows 7 ,same problem it display 3 tabs and not restore point tab

Comment: You could try with `info.Verb = "runas";`

Comment: unfortunately same problem