# error when run PowerShell command from cmd c#

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd, process

i want to execute this commands from c#:

```
@echo off
PowerShell "ForEach($v in (Get-Command -Name \"Set-ProcessMitigation\").Parameters[\"Disable\"].Attributes.ValidValues){Set-ProcessMitigation -System -Disable $v.ToString() -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}"
pause
```

i put the it in cmd file and run it using :

```
Process.Start(CMDFilePath);
```

but error occurre:

```
C:\Users\New-hwid\Desktop\Debug2>PowerShell "ForEach($v in (Get-Command -Name \"Set-ProcessMitigation\").Parameters[\"Disable\"].Attributes.ValidValues){Set-ProcessMitigation -System -Disable $v.ToString() -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}"
Get-Command : The term 'Set-ProcessMitigation' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:16
+ ForEach($v in (Get-Command -Name "Set-ProcessMitigation").Parameters[ ...
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-ProcessMitigation:String) [Get-Command], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCommandCommand

Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:15
+ ... rEach($v in (Get-Command -Name "Set-ProcessMitigation").Parameters["D ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

when i open cmd file normally it worked fine , but when i run it via Process.Start(...) this error happen, my OS is windows 10 64 bit, how to run CMD file without error? Thanks

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73999216/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74005878/10024425

Comment: it seems to be i have to run 64 bit powershell, because my project complied as prefer 32 bit, how to run 64 bit version of powrshell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74962285/open-restore-point-dialog-c-sharp/74962440?noredirect=1#comment132284933_74962440) , The issue that you're seeing is because of the File System Redirector which is occurring because you're running your program as 32-bit on your 64-bit OS. Therefore, you're executing %windir%\SysWOW64\SystemPropertiesProtection.exe (ex: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SystemPropertiesProtection.exe).
so i add In app.manifest, and replace

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

with

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

and modified the code to work with powershell:

```
   public static void OpenPowerShell(string Command)
        {
            try
            {
                string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "System32", "WindowsPowerShell","v1.0","powershell.exe");
              
                //environment variable windir has the same value as SystemRoot
                //use 'Sysnative' to access 64-bit files (in System32) if program is running as 32-bit process
                //use 'SysWow64' to access 32-bit files on 64-bit OS

                if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
                {
                    //filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "SysNative", "PowerShell.exe");
                    filename =System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "SysNative", "WindowsPowerShell", "v1.0", "powershell.exe");
                }
                
               
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filename);
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                startInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
                startInfo.Arguments = "-NoExit "+Command  ;
                Process.Start(startInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                FRM_MSG f = new FRM_MSG();
                f.ShowDLG(" ",
                            ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace.ToString(),
                            FRM_MSG.MSGIcon.Error,
                            FRM_MSG.BTNS.One,
                            new string[] { "Ok" });
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```